# How to scroll to row after loading data?

Tags: ios, swift

I`m working on a chat app example.

I want to scroll down after loading all datas but my code does not work. It loads all the data, sorts them and is displaying but it doesn't scroll down to the last message.

This is my code where I load all the datas and want to scroll down:

```
 //Downloads messages
func fetchData() {
    Message.downloadAllMessages(forUserID: (currentUser?.uid)!, completion: {[weak weakSelf = self] (message) in
        weakSelf?.items.append(message)
        weakSelf?.items.sort{ $0.timestamp < $1.timestamp }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let state = weakSelf?.items.isEmpty, state == false {
                weakSelf?.tableView.reloadData()
                weakSelf?.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath.init(row: self.items.count - 1, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: false)
            }
        }
    })
    Message.markMessagesRead(forUserID: (currentUser?.uid)!)
}
```

Here my customization:

```
 func customization() {
    self.imagePicker.delegate = self
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = self.barHeight
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    self.tableView.contentInset.bottom = self.barHeight
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom = self.barHeight
    self.navigationItem.title = self.currentUser?.username
    self.locationManager.delegate = self

    //ContainerView customization
    let extraViewsContainer = UIView.init()
    extraViewsContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(extraViewsContainer)
    self.topAnchorContraint = NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: extraViewsContainer, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 1000)
    self.topAnchorContraint.isActive = true
    extraViewsContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    extraViewsContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    extraViewsContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
    extraViewsContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    //PreviewView Customization
    extraViewsContainer.addSubview(self.previewView)
    self.previewView.isHidden = true
    self.previewView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.previewView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: extraViewsContainer.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    self.previewView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: extraViewsContainer.topAnchor).isActive = true
    self.previewView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: extraViewsContainer.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    self.previewView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: extraViewsContainer.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0
    //MapPreView Customization
    extraViewsContainer.addSubview(self.mapPreviewView)
    self.mapPreviewView.isHidden = true
    self.mapPreviewView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.mapPreviewView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: extraViewsContainer.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    self.mapPreviewView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: extraViewsContainer.topAnchor).isActive = true
    self.mapPreviewView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: extraViewsContainer.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    self.mapPreviewView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: extraViewsContainer.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    //NotificationCenter for showing extra views
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.showExtraViews(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "showExtraView"), object: nil)

}
```

I call both, `fetchData` and `customization` in viewDidLoad maybe there are some problems in `customization`

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Your problem may be a synchronization problem. Did you try to do appending and sorting process in the main thread?

Comment: I already call `fetchData` `viewDidLoad`. What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `selectRow` and `didSelectRowAt` before `scrollToRow`,

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let state = weakSelf?.items.isEmpty, state == false {
            weakSelf?.tableView.reloadData()
            let indexPath = IndexPath.init(row: self.items.count - 1, section: 0)
            weakSelf?.tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
            weakSelf?.tableView.delegate?.tableView?(weakSelf?.tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
            weakSelf?.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. Still doesn't work. It always stops in the middle of the chat. scrollToRow works but not to the bottom of the chat.

Comment: Are you trying this `weakSelf?.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)` or `weakSelf?.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .middle, animated: true)` ?

Comment: Please use `.bottom` instead of `.middle` in `scrollToRow` method

Comment: put in `.middle` but still doesn't work. I also tried `.bottoom` in `scrollToRow`

Comment: edited my question and extended the `customization`. I call love in viewDidLoad, so maybe there are so problems inside.